# Flow - Cannot get action.index because property index is missing

Tags: node.js, react-native, redux, expo, flowtype

I have the following code:

**src\types.js**

```
export type TLoadIndex = { type: string, index: number }
export type TLoadAll = { type: string }
export type TDeleteAll = { type: string }
export type TAction = TLoadIndex | TLoadAll | TDeleteAll;

export type TPlane = {
    title?: string,
    caption?: string,
    text?: string,
    image: string,
};
```

**src\store\plane\reducer.js**

```
import planeList from './planeList';
import { LOAD_INDEX, LOAD_ALL, DELETE_ALL } from './actions';
import type { TLoadIndex, TLoadAll, TDeleteAll, TAction, TPlane } from '../../types';

export default function (currentList: TPlane[] = [], action: TAction): TPlane[] {
    let newList: TPlane[] = currentList;
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOAD_INDEX:
            if (planeList[action.index])
                newList = [...currentList, planeList[action.index]];
            break;
        case LOAD_ALL:
            newList = planeList;
            break;
        case DELETE_ALL:
            newList = [];
            break;
    }
    return newList;
}
```

**My problem is:** when I run the following command:

```
> npm run flow
```

I get the following `flow` error:

```
Error -------------- src/store/plane/reducer.js:9:25

Cannot get action.index because:
 - property index is missing in TDeleteAll [1].
 - property index is missing in TLoadAll [1].

 [1]  5| export default function (currentList: TPlane[] = [], action: TAction): TPlane[] {
      6|        let newList: TPlane[] = currentList;
      7|        switch (action.type) {
      8|                case LOAD_INDEX:
      9|                        if (planeList[action.index])
     10|                                newList = [...currentList, planeList[action.index]];
     11|                        break;
     12|                case LOAD_ALL:


Error -------------- src/store/plane/reducer.js:10:49

Cannot get action.index because:
 - property index is missing in TDeleteAll [1].
 - property index is missing in TLoadAll [1].

 [1]  5| export default function (currentList: TPlane[] = [], action: TAction): TPlane[] {
      6|        let newList: TPlane[] = currentList;
      7|        switch (action.type) {
      8|                case LOAD_INDEX:
      9|                        if (planeList[action.index])
     10|                                newList = [...currentList, planeList[action.index]];
     11|                        break;
     12|                case LOAD_ALL:
     13|                        newList = planeList;
```

The point is that I don't want to add the property: `index` to the following types: `{ TLoadAll, TDeleteAll }` because that property needs to be tied only to type: `TLoadIndex`.

Probably the problem is how `flow` works internally with `switch`.

Any idea on how to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for this error is that currently action type annotations are too broad (`string`). The solution is to make them more narrow. A few changes will be needed to make this work.

1) Add narrow annotations to action types in the `actions`. Supposedly `actions` currently look like:

```
// @flow
export const LOAD_INDEX = 'LOAD_INDEX';
export const LOAD_ALL = 'LOAD_ALL';
export const DELETE_ALL = 'DELETE_ALL';
```

It should be changed to

```
export const LOAD_INDEX: 'LOAD_INDEX' = 'LOAD_INDEX';
export const LOAD_ALL: 'LOAD_ALL' = 'LOAD_ALL';
export const DELETE_ALL: 'DELETE_ALL' = 'DELETE_ALL';
```

2) Add more narrow annotation to action types in `types.js`.

**src\types.js**

```
import { LOAD_INDEX, LOAD_ALL, DELETE_ALL } from './actions';
export type TLoadIndex = { type: typeof LOAD_INDEX, index: number }
export type TLoadAll = { type: typeof LOAD_ALL}
export type TDeleteAll = { type: typeof DELETE_ALL}
export type TAction = TLoadIndex | TLoadAll | TDeleteAll;

export type TPlane = {
    title?: string,
    caption?: string,
    text?: string,
    image: string,
};
```